# Skipping "IF" function when working with structures

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct res{
int win;
int defeat;
}; 


struct tenis_player{
char name[20];
char last_name[20];
int pos;
char hand[10];
struct res comp;
}Ten[20];

int main(){
int i, n;
float comparison, br=0;
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    scanf("%s",&Ten[i].name);
    scanf("%s",&Ten[i].last_name);
    scanf("%d",&Ten[i].pos);
    scanf("%s",&Ten[i].hand);
    scanf("%d/%d",&Ten[i].comp.win,&Ten[i].comp.defeat);
    }
    printf("Results:\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){  
        comparison = Ten[i].comp.win/Ten[i].comp.defeat;
            if(Ten[i].hand == "left" && comparison>3){
                printf("%s %s %f",Ten[i].name,Ten[i].last_name,comparison);
                br++;
                printf("\n");}}
        if (br==0)
        printf("No tenis players");
return 0;
}
```

My code keeps skipping the "if(Ten[i].hand == "left" && comparison>3)" and just prints out "No tenis players" no matter what I input.
Any help would be appreciated ! :)

Comment: Read about [strcmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

Comment: Spelling aid: Tenis -> Tennis.

Answer (score 4):

In C when you do e.g. `Ten[i].hand == "left"` you are not comparing strings, you are comparing *pointers*. And in this case the two pointers will (and can) never be the same.

To compare strings you need to use the [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function:

```
if(strcmp(Ten[i].hand, "left")==0 && comparison>3){...}
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to have done it sadly :s

Comment: @voluc Then it's time to take out the *debugger* and step through the code line by line to see what it does and what the values of all variables are at each step.

Comment: `scanf("%d/%d",&Ten[i].comp.win,&Ten[i].comp.defeat);`  Look at this line closely and you will find your problem.

Comment: im supposed to have " / " in between the numbers since thats what the program thats testing this inputs.. is there another way to make it with the " / " , i have to keep them as int values since i have to divide them later on..